# Do I need all the WoW expansions in order to play the Worgen?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to buy all the released updates to begin playing WoW?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14348/do-i-need-to-buy-all-the-released-updates-to-begin-playing-wow)

I'm just starting a new account, and what I'm wondering is do I need to buy all of WoW original, The Burning Crusade, Wrath of the Lich King and Cataclysm expansions in order to start playing the Worgen race? Or could I just buy WoW and Cataclysm?

Comment: @Less Why didn't you vote close then? In WoW matters you're pretty much _the_ authority here.

Comment: I did. 3+ Weeks ago. The close vote expired.

Answer (score 4):

You do need both Burning Crusade and Wrath of the Lich King for Cataclysm content, including playing Worgen and Goblins.

If you're new to the game, might I recommend picking up a Gnome or Troll? Their starting areas have been fairly significantly redone, and from what I hear they're pretty sweet. Not as sweet as Worgen or Goblins, I take it, but still.