# Starting in World of Warcraft

Tags: world-of-warcraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to buy all the released updates to begin playing WoW?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14348/do-i-need-to-buy-all-the-released-updates-to-begin-playing-wow)

Which box do we have to buy in order to start playing in World of Warcraft? Do we need every expansion to start? or will the Cataclysm + Core game be enough?