# How to gift WoW to friend in France?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Have a friend homebound with cancer. Chemo makes him too sick to go out, and we (his American friends) want to entertain his mind. Might as well get him addicted to WoW! The current plan is to register an account in his name on the UK store on the EU domain, and he can access it even though he'll use the French version. Will that work? Blizzard/Battle.net is sooo not forthcoming about how the servers work.

If there's no other way, we have another French-speaking friend who could register him on the French domain, but that just complicates things...

Comment: If your friend is to be playing with his American friends, buying an EU copy is the wrong start - you will need the US copy if they play on the US servers

Answer (score 13):

It's worth noting before we start that World of Warcraft is a region locked game. It is available in a variety of regions (EU, US, TW, KR) but if you purchase a copy for another region it will not be compatible with all regions. If your friend is to be playing with his American friends, you will need the US copy if they play on the US servers

According to the various Blizzard sources, in order to gift a copy of World of Warcraft or one of its expansions to a friend you do the following;

> Simply add the “Digital Download” version to your cart, and once you complete the online purchasing process, you’ll be given the option to email your game code to a friend as a gift, or -- if you’d rather redeem the code yourself -- have it automatically filled in for you in Battle.net account management.

In order to play the whole of World of Warcraft (ie: get to level 90, explore all of the zones, etc) you will need to [purchase all of the expansion packs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/14348/27134) - only buying the base game will still provide a large amount of content to play, but will prevent your friend from playing any of the maximum level content (or indeed, some of the content before that such as Cataclysm content).

If you need any further assistance with this, or "official" help, I would recommend [contacting Blizzard directly](https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/contact).