# Wow expansion pack help

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Ok, first time useing this thing.....
Heres my question 
I want to buy wow in stores not useing the subscription so do I need to buy every upgrade (or expansion) or can I just but vanilla and get WoD. Or do I just need to buy vanilla. Pls keep it simple my brain is stressed I already played the trial and everything. Thank you for taking your time and reading

Comment: The game requires a subscription regardless of where you buy it, or how many expansions you have.

Comment: You can now fund the subscription with in-game gold -- I saw the other day that the current price for a "30 day game token" was around 22k of in-game gold. Technically it's still a subscription, but doesn't require charging a credit card.

Answer (score 4):

You can play the game for free using the starter edition

[EU Starter edition signup](https://eu.battle.net/account/creation/wow/signup/)

[US Starter edition signup](https://us.battle.net/account/creation/wow/signup/)

Once you get to level 20 you need to buy the game if you want to get to a higher level

If you buy the game you need to pay a subscription to access your characters above level 20, but if your subscription runs out you can still access any characters that are level 20 and below.

According to wowpedia you can reach level 90 with the standard game

[wowpedia - level cap](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Level_cap)

If you buy warlords of dreanor you get a character level boost to level 90

[battle.net - Level 90 Character Boost](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/level-90-character-boost)

See the following for a more detailed breakdown:

[Do I need to buy all the released updates to begin playing WoW?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14348/do-i-need-to-buy-all-the-released-updates-to-begin-playing-wow)